# How do I close App on Back button press in an Activity which is not the launcher activity in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle

I have a login Activity and Home Activity in my app. The login Activity is the launcher Activity and it checks if user is already logged in and then auto directs the user to the Home Activity if he is already logged in. Now when the user is in the Home Activity and presses the back button, I want the user to quit the app like the same behavior that occurs when back button is pressed on the launcher activity. How do i achieve this? I definitely don't want him to be taken to the login activity because he is logged in already.

What I am doing right now is this, I have added the 'clear top' intent flags but user goes back to the Login Activity with this:

```
val intent = Intent(AuthUI.getApplicationContext(), 
         HomeActivity::class.java) 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
startActivity(intent)
```

Also, I am not using the Navigation Library in android

Comment: Call `finish()` immediately after calling `startActivity()` to open the Home Activity. The Login Activity will be removed from the backstack as the Home Activity is opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can finish the Login activity after starting the Home Activity.

```
startActivity('intent that starts home activity')
finish()
```

Or
you can call the `finishAffinity()` on backpressed in the home activity

Answer (score 2):

I guess you'll be using an Explicit Intent to launch the HomeActivity after verification. Hence you can just call finish on the LoginActivity immediately after you start the Intent that launches your HomeActivity.

i.e

```
startActivity('intent that starts home activity')
finish()
```

Then when the user presses the back btn on the HomeActivity, they'll exit the app.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple choices there:

1. You could `finish()` your login activity, so that it gets removed from the activity back stack.
2. You could use fragments for these screens and not add the previous one to the backStack while replacing fragments.
3. You can override the `onBackPressed` method to see if the user is still logged in, so that you can route them to the correct activity.
4. You could think of having a launcher activity which is a dummy activity whose `onCreate()` opens either the login activity or the home activity based on user login state, so that the login activity does not open in case he is logged in already, but this would still have the same problem of having you to `finish()` this activity before moving to the next one.